# why my brownies taste bitter?

Tags: brownies

I made brownies with the recipe of this:

egg           : 2

coco powder   : 1/2 cup

white flour   : 1 cup

milk          : 1 cup

baking powder : 1 tea spoon

oil           : 1/2 cup

sugar         : 1 cup

then i put oil, egg, and sugar in the bowl and beat it then i add coco powder and white flour and again beat them all for 5 minutes. Then i add milk and start beater. And then i spreading less oil in the dish and then add my ready brownies in the dish.Then i put brownies in microwave oven for 8 minutes for bake.

This is the recipe that i made but the brownies which i made is always bitter. Whenever i made it taste bitter a lot but why?

I don't know what step i done wrong can u please let me know what i can do that my brownies taste not bitter anymore.

How can it taste changes?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Maybe you need another recipe? (Unfortunately, recipe requests are off-topic here.)

Comment: thanks for welcome me and my question is why my brownies taste bitter?is this off topic?

Comment: Hello Aaisha and welcome! You're question is fine. And we appreciate the details you provided.

Comment: 1 tsp is a very large amount of baking powder, but I'm not sure if the name "baking powder" refers to the same product all over the world.

Comment: Is your oil rancid?

Comment: no not at all @DouglasHeld

Comment: so can u tell me the quantity of baking powder ? which i add in brownies@ThePhoton

Comment: Does your baking powder fizz or foam in water? Because if it does not, you may be using baking soda instead. Happened to me once and it had a almost bitter taste to it.

Comment: it does not, as @ThePhoton said about the quantity so now i thought it taste bitter bcoz of quantity.. but fine i try baking soda instead of baking powder

Comment: I usually see 1/4 or 1/2 tsp baking powder, but also only 1/2 cup flour, so maybe your ratio isn't too far off. I did find [one recipe](https://smittenkitchen.com/2012/08/my-favorite-brownies/) with no baking powder at all.

Answer (score 6):

Unsweetened Cocoa powder is a very bitter ingredient, and 1/2 a cup of it seems like a lot considering the ratios. If you want your brownies less bitter then you may want to reduce the cocoa some, or add more sugar, or do both. Try reducing your cocoa by 2 tbsp and adding 2 tbsp more sugar, adjust the ratios that way until you have the right balance.